# Using require_once for parent-directory not working but is working in sub-directories

Tags: theme-development, templates, include, get-template-part, template-include

I'm building a custom theme and I'm attempting to use `require_once __DIR__ . '/templates/variables.php'` in my `footer.php` file, to keep from repeating code that contains variable information... I keep getting an error telling me that my variable is undefined.

The strange thing is that when I use `require_once __DIR__ . '/../variables.php'` in my `/pages/content.php` file `require_once` does work and the variables are being defined correctly and I therefore access their data as intended.  Any reason as to why this isn't working in directories above the variables.php template directory but are working in directories below it?

Here is my file structure:

```
my_theme
       |
       |__footer.php
       |
       |__/templates
          |
          |__variables.php
          |
          |__/pages
             |
             |__content.php
```

Comment: Are you including the file ***after*** you try to use the variables set in the file?

Comment: No, I'm calling it before. It's the first thing I'm calling when the script runs.  So its `<?php require_once __DIR__ . '/templates/variables.php' /* Other code goes here */ ?>`

Comment: Your description makes it seem like the path is wrong. Dump the generated pathes and compare them.

Comment: I did... thats why I was confused because the path was correct.

Comment: Something has to be different-- a slash, something.

Comment: When using `require_once __DIR__ . '/../variables.php’;` in the pages/content.php file
`echo __DIR__;` returns `/var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/myTheme/templates/pages` at which point I’m appending the `templates/variables.php` file.

When using `require_once __DIR__ . '/templates/variables.php’;`
`echo __DIR__;` returns `/var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/myTheme` at which point I’m appending the `templates/variables.php` file.  In these examples the `require_once` is working in the `content.php` file but not in the `footer.php`